# Check if group exists mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

This is my table structure

**groupings**

```
id groupName 
1  group1
2  group2
3  group3
4  andSoOn
```

**group_members**(correct)

```
groupingId accountId groupLeader
1          5001      5001
1          5002      5001     
2          5001      5001
2          5002      5001
2          5003      5001
3          5001      5001
3          5002      5001
3          5003      5001
3          5004      5001
```

here's my problem, every group should be unique, in a way that the members should not be the same in a group...

***for example :***

**group_members**(wrong)

```
groupingId accountId groupLeader
1          5001      5001
1          5002      5001     
2          5001      5001
2          5002      5001
2          5003      5001
3          5001      5001
3          5002      5001
3          5003      5001
```

an insert statement with the groupingId = **3** will fail because 5001,5002,5003 already exists on groupingId = **2**

what should be my select statement to check if the members already exists in a group...
btw, im using PHP for this

Comment: it should fail when you insert 5001,5002,5003 because it already exists on groupingId = **2**

Comment: You mean you want to check always when you add an accountId to a group if there is a other group with the same accountIds? When there is one you not want that the accountId will be inserted.

Comment: Have you really thought this through? Because this would actually also prevent any kind of overlap between groups (unless you mix the order when selecting members).

Comment: Ah i think i understand now, after reading the answers. You want to check always, when you want to add a complete group if there is one with the same values. I think liquorvicar has the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this

```
SELECT groupingId, COUNT(*) AS accounts_present
FROM group_members
WHERE accountId IN (5001,5002,5003)
GROUP BY groupingId
HAVING accounts_present=3 // 3 here is the number of accounts in the "group", i.e. in the IN clause
```

This will return all groupingIds that have all the relevant accountIds. If it returns nothing you can be sure it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

This query gives you unique string for every different group

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(accountId, ',', groupLeader) SEPARATOR '|')  FROM group_members GROUP BY groupingId;
```

So this will give you number of different groups

```
SELECT count(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(accountId, ',', groupLeader) SEPARATOR '|') AS unique_string FROM group_members GROUP BY groupingId) AS tmp_table;
```

Now you need to compare it with number of groups.